# how to delete /usr/local/bin/docker-compose Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose

I tried to install docker-compose according to the official documentation, with curl:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.27.4/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

But it kind of did not work out, I do not know what the error is. If I try to start docker-compose I get this error:

```
[26209] Cannot open self /usr/local/bin/docker-compose or archive /usr/local/bin/docker-compose.pkg
```

I wanted to delete this file /usr/local/bin/docker-compose but then I am getting an `Operation not permitted error`. I can not even change permissions. I tried to do it with `sudo` but still no luck!

Answer (score 1):

fixed the error it was due to the file being immutable. I could see it with:

```
    lsattr path/to/file
```

if it was immutable the output was something like this: ----i--------e--

With `sudo chattr -i  path/to/file` I could fix it.